# Suitable Android Foreground service

Tags: android, kotlin, service, alarm, foreground

Does android have some suitable foreground service for the job who will keep track of time, very similar to the work of an alarm clock?

User choosing the time then the app creates request, close the app, and application track this time for request.

Comment: can your please elaborate your question please

Comment: are you looking for long running background service ?

Comment: I need service which will make request to server at a specific time.

Comment: why don't you use work manager ?